# How do I call a jQuery function on an a with href?

Tags: jquery

I have a binded jquery function on an a element with a href attribute

If the a has no href attribute, the function bound to the click event will fire

If it has a href attribute it wont

Help?

Comment: It's not that the click event won't fire, it's that the HREF is stomping all over your click event.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you want to `return false` from your handler, which will cancel the ANCHOR's following the HREF.

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="test">Test</a>

$('#test').click(function(){
    alert('test');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MysjS/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //preventing the link from being followed.
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Correct, for all we know there is only one A tag.

Comment: That's true. That would (usually) be an unusual webpage, but that could be true. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the event is indeed firing, but since you have an `<a>` with an `href` the browser is also reloading or switching pages. If you want to prevent that behavior you need to `return false;` from you click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    if(!$(this).attr("href")) {
       //fire
   } 
});
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your `if` statement, as well as your selector being *broad*, to say the least.

Comment: Absolutely! And how do you plan to prevent an ANCHOR's href element from being followed? ;)

Comment: Well, that's the thing here. While everyone is going for `preventDefault()`, one could also read the question such that he is trying to execute the function _only_ on anchors _without_ href specified. See? That way we have covered all possible answers for a badly asked question...

Comment: Except it doesn't work that way. If you read the OP's question, you'll see that it's when an HREF attribute is present that the "problem" appears, otherwise there is not an issue. The HREF will always overrule a click handler unless the click handler cancels the action (either with `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`). Otherwise, the browser has already followed the link before the click handler has responded.

Comment: For example, see if the console fires in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/MysjS/1/ (Firebug or Chrome console).

Comment: okay, enough of this. here's what I'm talking about. over an out http://jsfiddle.net/MysjS/2/

Comment: *If the a has no href attribute, the function bound to the click event will fire If it has a href attribute it wont* That's verbatim from the question. As well as the question title, *How do I call a jQuery function on an a with href?*. I'm not making this up. There's only two answers, `return false` and `.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Better use javascript:void(0); in anchor tag -> http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptvoid.php

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution

```
href="javascript:alert('Hello');"
```